# Bill Of Material quantities SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm wanting to list sum of the bill of materials. I've made some example code:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da913/1

As you can see that the bill of materials are duplicating up due to recursive level.

So, I was hoping for result to:

`┌────────────┬───────────┬────────────┐
│ParentPartId│ChildPartId│ChildPartQty│
├────────────┼───────────┼────────────┤
│SHOWER-A    │GLASS-A    │2           │
├────────────┼───────────┼────────────┤
│GLASS-A     │SOMETHING-A│10          │
├────────────┼───────────┼────────────┤
│SOMETHING-A │SOMETHING-B│30          │
└────────────┴───────────┴────────────┘`

I'm thinking about group by highest recursive level but just feels messy and hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da913/27) is a solution that might be helpful :

```
; with cte_gettopparents as 
(
  select a.*, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a.ParentPartId) as ordr
  from   BillOfMaterial a 
  where  not exists
  (
    select 1 
    from   BillOfMaterial b
    where  b.ChildPartId = a.ParentPartId
  )
)
--select * from cte_gettopparents
,
cte_getallchildren as
(
  select *
  from   cte_gettopparents
  union  all
  select a.ParentPartId, a.ChildPartId ,a.ChildPartQty * b.ChildPartQty,b.ordr
  from   BillOfMaterial a join cte_getallchildren b
  on     b.ChildPartId = a.ParentPartId
)

select ParentPartId, ChildPartId ,ChildPartQty, ordr as [hierarchyid]
from   cte_getallchildren
order  by ordr,ChildPartId
```

if you want distinct results then use [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da913/23) :

```
select Distinct ParentPartId, ChildPartId ,ChildPartQty
from   cte_getallchildren
order  by ChildPartQty
```